# No Buffer Space available(maximum connection reached?) Form Postgres EDB Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, socketexception

We are facing an exception while connecting to database through our java application. The stack trace is as follows

```
com.edb.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
 at com.edb.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:189)
 at com.edb.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
 at com.edb.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:161)
 at com.edb.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
 at com.edb.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
 at com.edb.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
 at com.edb.Driver.connect(Driver.java:266)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.edb.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
 at com.edb.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:115)
 ... 20 more
```

When the error occured we were not able to connect to internet and DB and had to reboot the system. But the error occured again after 3 days at same code i.e while connecting to DB. We checked TCP connections using netstat. But there were not many TCP connections i.e it has not reached the max limit.

Our application has multiple long running Java processes that pools the DB connections (not more than 60) and keeps it alive for firing the next query (as it has to poll the DB every 2 seconds). Some of the queries in our application are joining large tables (10 million records) to get the related data.

We are using following System and applications

- Windows 2003 server SP2
- Java 1.6
- Postgres Plus Advanced server 8.4   Database
- `edb-jdbc14.jar` driver for connection DB from Java

We have used the default configuration of Postgres DB except increasing the connection to 120 from 100.

Has anybody encountred the same error with postgres edb driver?

Can anybody help us finding the solution?

Comment: So anything in the server log?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a client side problem - it never manages to even connect to the server. It is *not* the error you get from the PostgreSQL or Advanced Server when it runs out of available server connections.

The problem is either in the resources for your client program/JVM, or somewhere in the EDB JDBC driver. If you can't find something incorrect in your JVM, and since you're on PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server, I would suggest you use EnterpriseDB support for help with their JDBC driver. (Which is different from the PostgreSQL one)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a client-side Windows issue, not necessarily a code issue.
Please refer [to my answer to a similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29702281/203860)