# HornetQ exception in netty connection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tcp, jboss, hornetq

I am working with HornetQ 2.2.5 Final and JAVA TCP listener. My listener class able to read data packet from GPS device and store in hornetQ. My system is working very well, but suddenly after 3 hours my system behaves very badly. Suppose while storing data from TCP listener to hornetQ and get an exception, code reach to finally block and in finally block, I am calling `contextInitialized(event)` method again so `serverSocket` object and hornetQ intialization happens again, but at the time of hornetQ initialization, I am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Failed to create netty connection
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

Please help me understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at others who had similar issues?

Mainly

1. [java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068423/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached)
2. [No Buffer Space available(maximum connection reached?) Form Postgres EDB Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656128/no-buffer-space-availablemaximum-connection-reached-form-postgres-edb-driver)

Comment: Yes i looked into that , but i am not able to find a solution, Please help me to understand why HornetQ object is creating more and more. thanks

Comment: I think the documentation clearly described the behavior of the server socket. Depending on the type of the connection. Here is the documentation for NIOServerSocketFactory http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioServerSocketChannelFactory.html

Comment: i am using simple ServerSocket class not netty ServerSocketChannel, but i am using HornetQ, so might be this error is happening due to hornetQ, Please suggest me how to fix it.